# Spring-Boot Compatible In Memory Database that Support String Array (String []) Data Type

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, h2, in-memory-database

I have a Spring-Boot application and it contains an Object Model that are mapped to Postgres Database using ORM. This model contains a field of type String array that is supported by Postgres. I wanted to create an in memory Database for my integration test cases so I used H2 database.

The problem is that H2 database doesn't support String array data type. There is an "Array" data type in H2 but it takes values as "Object" data type.

I have tried other in-memory databases that are compatible with Spring-Boot like HSQL and Apache Derby but it didn't solve my problem.

Is there any way to map String array to H2 database? Or any better solution to such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help you, but did you configure your H2 to work with Postgres?

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

and look for

> PostgreSQL Compatibility Mode

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't solve the problem of String Array